# How to get the last online status of an user with JDA( Java discord API)

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

How can I get the last online status of an user in a guild by using JDA?
I mean, not the current online status but when was the last time that the user was online.

I searched on Google but didn't find any solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord does not provide that information through their API, so you'll have to watch for `PRESENCE_UPDATE` (or [UserUpdateOnlineStatusEvent](https://javadoc.io/doc/net.dv8tion/JDA/latest/net/dv8tion/jda/api/events/user/update/UserUpdateOnlineStatusEvent.html) in JDA) events from the gateway and store timestamps in a database whenever someone goes offline.